# Kotlin - Change bottomNavigationView icon color dynamically

Tags: android, kotlin, icons, bottomnavigationview

In my viewmodel class I have a list .

The idea is that when this list is not empty , my card icon of bottomnavigationview changes to red .

With below code I can only change the background color of icon . But I need change the icon color .

Code :

```
class Viewmodel : ViewModel()

val listModel = MutableLiveData<List<ModelCart>>()
 

 fun changeColor(view:View) {

        if (listModel.value != null)

          view.background = ColorDrawable(Color.RED)
    }
```

and in my activity :

```
 bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->

  viewmodel.changeColor(this.bottomNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.cart))

   when (menuITem.itemId) {...}
```

How Can I change the icon color of my cart specifically ?

I really apreciate your help .

Comment: You should subscribe to LiveData on UI via listModel.observe and track changes

Answer (score 0):

color of icons in bottomNavigationView is set according to the colorPrimary in the selected Theme.

So to change the color of the bottomNavigationView create themes with different colors and change the theme or style of the bottomNavigationView dynamically